# VBA how to use postal code to get distance and time between two location

Tags: json, excel, vba

```vb
Function OneMapAPI(ByVal originPostal As String, ByVal destinationPostal As String) As String
 
     Dim xmlHttp As Object
     Dim response As String
     Dim distance As Double
     Dim duration As Double
 
     Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
     
     xmlHttp.Open "GET", "https://developers.onemap.sg/privateapi/routingsvc/route?" & _
         "start=" & originPostal & "&end=" & destinationPostal & "&routeType=<API KEY>", False
     
     xmlHttp.Send
     
     response = xmlHttp.ResponseText
     
     ' Print out the response to the Immediate Window
     Debug.Print response
     
     ' Parse the JSON response
     Dim jsonResponse As Object
     Set jsonResponse = JsonConverter.ParseJson(response)
     
     ' Get the distance and duration values
     On Error Resume Next
     distance = Val(jsonResponse("route_summary")("total_distance")) / 1000 ' Convert to kilometers
     If Err.Number <> 0 Then
         Debug.Print "Error getting distance: " & Err.Description
     End If
     duration = Val(jsonResponse("route_summary")("total_time")) / 3600  ' Convert to hours
     If Err.Number <> 0 Then
         Debug.Print "Error getting duration: " & Err.Description
     End If
     On Error GoTo 0
     
     OneMapAPI = "Distance: " & Format(distance, "0.00") & "km, Duration: " & Format(duration, "0.00") & "h"
End Function

Sub TestOneMapAPI()
     Dim result As String
     
     result = OneMapAPI("380016", "658713")
     
     MsgBox result 
End Sub
```

I have been trying to troubleshoot this error

> {"error":"Your location provided is not valid."}
> Error getting distance: Type mismatch
> Error getting duration: Type mismatch

When I run the code I have an API key and yes these postal codes are valid addresses in `oneMap`.

Comment: https://www.onemap.gov.sg/docs/#routing-service describes how to use the API.  You're passing in postcodes but it expects WGS84-formatted coordinates for the start and end points.  You also seem to be passing in your API token for the `routeType`

Comment: for Request.Open "GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?" & "origin= " & Origin & "&destination=" & Destination & "&mode=" & Mode & "&key=" & ApiKey, False

=>the values for Origin and Destination are: "postalcode, Country" and for Mode is one of ("driving","walking","bicycling")